# Google Sheets: COUNTIF in multiple columns but only ONCE if more than 1 in same row

Tags: google-sheets, countif

```
ColA            ColB            ColC            ColD            ColE
DATE            COUNTRY 1       COUNTRY 2       COUNTRY 3       COUNTRY 4
01/xx/2017      INDONESIA       GERMANY         PHILIPPINES     PAKISTAN
01/xx/2017      MOROCCO         MOROCCO         MOROCCO         ITALY
23/xx/2017      USA             UK              NETHERLANDS     MOROCCO
23/xx/2017      MOROCCO         TANZANIA        AUSTRALIA       SWEDEN
```

What formula can I use to count the occurrences of a country (let's say `Morocco`) in `ColB:ColE` but only counting it ONCE if more than an occurrence appear in the same row? In this case for example the result should be `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(MMULT(--(B2:E5="MOROCCO"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E5)^0)),">0"))
```

BTW any logical expression may be used instead of `--(B2:E5="MOROCCO")`

---

### **How it works**

the first act is to have `true` and `false` array: ArrayFormula(B2:E5="MOROCCO")

The output is like this

```
true    false    false    false 
true    true     true     false
false   false    false    true
false   false    false    false
```

Then we need to convert it into `1 / 0` array. Simple math operation will do it:

`ArrayFormula(--(B2:E5="MOROCCO"))`

the output now is:

```
    1       0       0       0 
    1       1       1       0
    0       0       0       1
    0       0       0       0
```

Now we may add them by row: use `mmult` function. But first we need a column of `1` with the number of elements = number of columns in our array. To get it use formula:
`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E6)^0))`

The result is:

```
    1    
    1    
    1    
    1
```

And finally use mmult: `=ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(B2:E6="MOROCCO"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E6)^0)))`

The result is:

```
    1    
    3    
    1    
    0
```

I really don't know, why it works. just use this.

And final step is counting all that is `> 0` = 3

Comment: I've added some details to the answer. If it matches, please mark it as correct.

Comment: MMult multiplies all elements in a row of the first array by all elements in a column of the second array. So for the second row (for example) you get 1*1+1*1+1*1+0*1 = 3.