# Google Sheets - Multiple Columns Count if Cell Contains String... but only Count it once if string in same row more than once

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, countif

I've seen [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063271/google-sheets-countif-in-multiple-columns-but-only-once-if-more-than-1-in-same) that comes close to what I want. In that example a person wanted to count the occurrence of a string across multiple columns - but only once if the string appeared in the same row more than once.

The OP in that article had a block of columns all together, B2:E5. My situation is that there are some columns that I don't want searched inbetween the ones that I do want to search.

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
"a"   "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"
"a"   "b"   "a"   "c"   "d"
"b"   "a"   "c"   "d"   "d"
"b"   "c"   "a"   "d"   "c"
```

Lets say I want to count the instances of "a" in Col1, Col3, and Col5.

`=COUNTIF({Col1:Col1;Col3:Col3;Col5:Col5},"a")`
returns 4 because it sees two values in the second row. But I don't want to count how many cells contain a string, I want to count the row if any of the cells have that string.

How do I get the formula to count only once regardless of how many times the string appears in the row?

Comment: What would be your desired output then?

Comment: 3... so the second row only gets counted once, despite have more than one instance of "a" in the filtered columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sum(byrow(choosecols(A:E,1,3,5),lambda(Σ,ifna(xmatch("a",Σ)^0))))
```

[image]